# D3 Canvas brush and zoom

Tags: canvas, d3.js

I am working on a heat map using canvas. I am not using SVG because I want to render data points more than 30,000 . I found this example of using brush for focus+context.
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

But this works for SVG and I want to use this functionality of brush for Canvas.
Is it even possible to do that with d3?
If not what can be the workaround ideas to implement focus+context on canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Building Scalable Charts with D3.js and Canvas
https://github.com/xoor-io/d3-canvas-example
It Supports:

1. Drawing on canvas which useful for huge data.
2. Zoom and panning.
3. Brush and Zoom that help in your case.

Answer (score 1):

[d3-brush](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/) specifically uses SVG:

> The d3-brush module implements brushing for mouse and touch events using SVG

It's possible though to put an SVG on top of a canvas layer, see https://observablehq.com/@rdmurphy/combining-html-canvas-svg-flatbush-for-super-efficient-hov or https://observablehq.com/@d3/mona-lisa-histogram for example

Answer (score 0):

This example uses an svg brush with a background canvas: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/0d20834e3d5a46138752f86b9b79727e

This example creates a canvas heatmap: 
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3074470

This example creates a canvas heatmap with zoom and no brush: http://bl.ocks.org/tommct/8116740

This can be done by combining the zoomable canvas with an svg brush.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is it possible for you to join all these things as you said and make a fiddle?

Comment: Each piece of code works but there is no detail description whats going on  like when brush is moved . If some one with detail knowledge can combine these things together it would be really helpful.

Comment: @Achilles,  you just asked if it was possible, and the answer is yes :).  Unfortunately, I don't have time to make you a fiddle today.